# Set Drag Image react-sortable-hoc before onSortStart

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-sortable-hoc

With `react-sortable-hoc` I am unable to set the DragImage.

I have elements that take up a large amount of DOM space and it is hard to manage from a user experience perspective.

In my example, when the user starts to drag the items are collapsed, however the drag image is still full size, causing confusion.

I created a [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-sortable-hoc-starter-7v5px) to demo my problem, however my actual production application takes up much more space.

**UPDATE**

`updateBeforeSortStart` instead of `onSortStart` is what I was looking for

Updated [Updated CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-sortable-hoc-starter-sp6ie)

Answer (score -1):

`updateBeforeSortStart` instead of `onSortStart` is what I was looking for

Updated [Updated CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-sortable-hoc-starter-sp6ie)